# Click on dropdown menu with selenium, scrape doesn't work

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to scrape Data from http://www.squawka.com/match-results. First I want to choose the league in the Dropdown menu, e.g. The Americas, German Bundesliga. My code choose the The Americas but the new Data isn't load. I think there is some javascript in the background that is not fired up.

Here the code. I use scrapy and selenium with chromedirver but I tested firefox driver too with no success.

```
import scrapy

from squawka.items import SquawkaItem
from scrapy.http import FormRequest, Request

from selenium import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import time

class SquawkaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "squawka"
    allowed_domains = ["squawka.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.squawka.com/match-results"]

def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/fabian/chromedriver')

def parse(self, response):
    self.driver.get(response.url)
    time.sleep(5)
    Dropdown = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='league-filter-list']/option[contains(text(), 'The Americas')]").click()
```

I hope someone can help me.

Thank

Comment: I cannot even choose "The Americas" manually..

Comment: Really? Thats strange. Manually I can choose each league in my webbrowser, e.g. The Americas or German Bundesliga.

Comment: site is working correctly. This is not a final solution but read about implicit/explicit waits to get rid of that sleep! (http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits). For example you could until element .//*[@id='league-filter-list'] (the dropdown) is available.

Comment: @metar Do you mean something like that: wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10) and then in the next line element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'league-filter-list'))). The code is working. Is it right? Is my scraper waiting until the Dropdown is clickable?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be Resolved by the **combination of wait time and Select()** statement.
Here in this case, you need to put some Wait time. Both Implicit/Explicit wait will work here. I have tried with **Implicit Wait**.

I have tried with the below code and it is selecting "The Americas" from the drop-down.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class ChromeDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://www.squawka.com/match-results");
        System.out.println("Entered Url");
        WebElement element1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='league-filter-list']"));
        Select sel = new Select(element1);
        sel.selectByVisibleText("The Americas");
        System.out.println("The Americans is selected");
    }
}
```

Note:- Application is designed in such a way that, you select anything from drop-down and again it will switch back to "Top 5 European Leagues".**But i am able to select "The Americas" with the above code.**

Comment: Puuuh, okay now I'm a little confused. Is that python code? And to your note. You said you can choose "The Americas" and then it springs back to top 5 European Leagues. My code make the same but the the problem is that the homepage doesn't load the Data from the league. If I choose the German Bundesliga there will no Data from the German Bundesliga, but it load something else.

Comment: I did it manually, selected "German Bundesliga" from drop-down, but still it loads the data for something else.

Comment: If I use my own browser and I choose "German Bundesliga" manually, than it works fine. But in the Scraper it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
Because you are not switching to the frame .You have to switch to that Frame before selecting the value.
```

driver.switchTo().frame(name_or_id);

Now select the value from dropdown.